# iOS Application_Home/Library/Caches directory being cleared extremely often

Tags: ios, airwatch

We are seeing an error complained about by the users of one of our applications. To the best of my knowledge, the users that are complaining of this issue are all using devices managed by airwatch.

The underlying issue is that when the app is shutdown, after a very short period of time (say about 5 minutes), when the device is locked, the Application_Home/Library/Caches directory gets cleared out. This seems to have a number of bad side effects:

1. files that were downloaded from the server are having to be downloaded again (everytime), thus defeating the purpose of using the cache
2. offline access of the app is impossible, if the cache was deleted at the wrong time. Since it is getting cleared out so quickly, this is probably happening all the time
3. probably increased data charges and bandwidth use

I don't really know anything about airwatch. Is there any way to configure this kind of behaviour in airwatch? How would I go about communicating this information to our client so that they may be able to investigate the problem?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question since it about configuring some 3rd party tool. You should ask this on whatever support forum that airwatch provides.

Comment: @rmaddy ok I'll try to do that as well. My initial impression is that their support forum is typically awful

Answer (score 0):

We have observed the same symptoms with our application. We have tested devices locally not using an MDM and cannot replicate these symptoms. I will try to reach out AirWatch but they